# Place elements in columns using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to do a grid of 2 columns in small screen and 4 in bigger.

The thing is I put on thoose grid `<article>`but none of them are of same height and this is making the screen bugging. 
And since they are generated by Laravel and a foreach I can't place them by hand.

So I came up whith the idea of giving them an index and append them to my grid after the elements are loaded.
But actually this is not working at all; works for the two first elements and then it seems not to get anymore the index.

Here is what I've done that way you get how this work :

### HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" id="A"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" id="B"></div>
<div class="hidden-sm col-md-3" id="C"></div>
<div class="hidden-sm col-md-3" id="C"></div>

<?php $i=0 ?>
@foreach($object as $anything)
  <article id="index<?php echo($i++) ?>" >
    <title>{{$anything -> title}}</title>
    ...
    ...
  </article>
@endforeach
```

### jQuery

```
$('article').each(function(){
  var index = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/)[0];
  n=0;
  if(index == 1+2*n) $(this).appendTo('#A');
  if(index == 2+2*n) $(this).appendTo('#B');
  n++;
})
```

And here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11481/)

### Edit (Solved)

Finaly manage to do it using this function if this could help someone one day. Still, I dont get what is the big difference between the two function...

```
$('article').each(function(){
    var index = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/)[0];
    if(index %2 == 1) $(this).appendTo('#A');
    if(index %2 == 0) $(this).appendTo('#B');
});
```

Comment: Wow.. that is a overcomplicated way of doing things.Does it work at all? Because you don't have elements with ID `A` or `B`. You have elements with an attribute `index` of `A` and `B`.

Comment: Ho sorry my index is actually id

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle code\

Comment: So why don't you make the `foreach` have `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` instead of 0 - 3?

Comment: @putvande you mean something like every 2 items add id="B", every 3 item add id="C" ..
I have no idea how to do that

Comment: No, the `foreach` you do in Laravel. Just make it loop over the alphabet instead of numbers.

Comment: @putvande still not getting what you mean by that :/ This foreach display objects with multiples variables like tittle, price etc. The whole code is too long and while confuse the question

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan provided

Comment: Alright. But what about the question that it stops after the second one. That is quite obvious as your code stops there too. It is only appending something to `#A` and `#B`

Comment: @putvande Why does it stop since it is going throug every article it shall continue on and on till there is no more article... Maybe is it the condition that is not good -> `1+2*n` ? But when I write it in consol it works just fine :/

Comment: Because your code stops there. It doesn't magically continue.

Comment: @putvande Why doesn't it continue over and over since I'm using an `each()` function ?

Comment: @putvande I still dont get what was wrong but if you want to know I manage to do it using modulo. I've edit my question.